# ROOT: TTreeReader and TVector3

Tags: c++, root-framework

I hope someone with knowledge of ROOT's TTreeReader and TVector3 classes can help me out.

I am trying to use TTreeReader to read my TTree which contains a TVector3.

```
class MuseSelector : public TSelector {
public : 

    TH1D* h_doca_;
    TH1D* h_vertex_z_;

    TTreeReader fReader;
    TTreeReaderValue<double> mDoca;
    TTreeReaderValue<TVector3> mVertex;

    MuseSelector(TTree * = 0): mDoca(fReader, "recon_doca"), mVertex(fReader, "recon_vertex") {}

    virtual ~MuseSelector() {}
    virtual void    Init(TTree *tree);
    virtual void    SlaveBegin(TTree *tree);
    virtual Bool_t  Process(Long64_t entry);
    virtual void    Terminate();
    virtual Int_t   Version() const { return 2; }

    ClassDef(MuseSelector,0);

};

void MuseSelector::Init( TTree *tree)
{

    fReader.SetTree(tree);

}

void MuseSelector::SlaveBegin(TTree *tree)
{

    h_doca_ = new TH1D("h_doca_", "", 100, 0, 100);
    h_vertex_z_ = new TH1D("h_vertex_z_", "", 50, -100, 100);
    GetOutputList()->Add(h_doca_);
    GetOutputList()->Add(h_vertex_z_);

}

Bool_t MuseSelector::Process(Long64_t entry)
{

    fReader.SetEntry(entry);

    h_doca_->Fill(*mDoca, 1);
    h_vertex_z_->Fill((*mVertex)->z(), 1);

    return kTRUE;

}

void MuseSelector::Terminate()
{


    h_doca_->Print();
    h_doca_->Draw();
    h_vertex_z_->Draw();

}
```

I run this class in ROOT with:

```
TChain *fChain = new TChain("T"); fChain->AddFile("anamuse.root");
fChain->Process("MuseSelector.C");
```

Where anamuse.root contains a Tree called "T", which contains a TVector3.

I get this error when I run that.

```
Error in <TTreeReaderValueBase::GetBranchDataType()>: Unknown type and class combination: -1, TVector3
Error in <TTreeReaderValueBase::CreateProxy()>: The branch recon_vertex contains data of type {UNDETERMINED TYPE}, which does not have a dictionary.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: discussed [in the root-forum](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/ttreereader-and-tvector3/26887)

Answer (score 2):

And the conclusion of the discussion at the ROOT forum: that was a bug, it is fixed since a while, e.g. 6.10.08 has that fix. Upgrade ROOT and it will work!